# Can't use grep for Windows?

Tags: cmd, grep

I am running Windows 10 on this laptop and recently was recommend to install grep. Well I did that by installing it with a program called GNUWin32.

For some reason I can't get grep to work. Maybe I'm stupid? I don't know but when I type the grep command in CMD it doesn't recognize it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add the bin subdirectory of the installation path to the PATH variable?

Comment: Thank you, it works now :).